# How to upload a static website with firebase

Tags: firebase-hosting

I'm going a bit mad trying to update my static website using Firebase, I recently had to re-install everying on my machine and can't remember how I managed to connect and upload my files previously.

I'm sure it's just something incredibly simple related to the public directory folder but I can't workout what. When I go to deploy the project it tells me that it's uploaded 150 files which is correct and I can see in my Firebase account under the "hosting" section that these files have been uploaded but when I view the site I just get a genreric "Welcome Firebase Hosting Setup Complete" screen.

Just to clarify if my project's route (containing index.html etc) is located under "C:\site" what should I enter for the public directory? I've tried a slash, leaving it blank, entering "." and half a dozen other options without any joy. I also tried moving them to a folder titled "public" under "site" but that doesn't appear to make any difference either.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Probably when you init a project you type yes to set up index.html file.

Comment: In a file `firebase.json` you have `"public": "path"` to a public folder. And check are you have correct `index.html` file in this public directory.

Comment: Where did you run `firebase init`? That should be in the same directory or (more typically) above as the HTML you want to deploy.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, yes it was something as simple as tthe index.html file being overwritten at some point! I kept the public folder as "." and replaced the index file and it's fine now!